# Stagger : how to return to the the initial position

Tags: reactjs, gsap

Good morning.

I start with GSAP and try to make an animation for my input to return to the initial position that I enter in the css.

function Pannel({className, open, children}) {
const [Isopen, setIsopen] = React.useState(false);

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('.pannel__input');
    console.log(input)
    console.log(open)
    if (open == true) {
        TweenMax.staggerTo(input, 1, {left:0, ease: "power2.easeout"}, 0.2);
    } else if (open != Isopen) {
        TweenMax.staggerFrom(input, 0.4, {left:0, ease: "power2.easeout"}, 0.2);
    }

    setIsopen(open);
}, [open]);

return (
    <div className={className + " " + (Isopen? "open" : "close")}>
        {children}
    </div>
)
```

I start to made a staggerTo that allow to my input to appear on the screen.
After clicking on a button I made a staggerFrom and I want that staggerFrom return my input to his original position, but actually it stay at his actual position. What I must change to allow my input to desappear from the screen. The initial position can change so I can't enter raw value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Romain. You're using a lot of the old GSAP syntax which is one of [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes/). As for your question, it'd be best to record the value at the start and then use that recording when you need it. If GSAP were to always keep track of the value at the start of every property of every target of every tween *just incase* it were needed sometime in the future that'd be a huge waste of memory and processing.